# Use font Times LT (Linotype) in LaTeX

Tags: fonts

I've searched for an answer to the following question, but I have not found a precise answer (or at least not an answer that worked for me). So this is it. I do have the original Times font (in Type 1 format) from Linotype, font name TimesLT. I would like to use them in LaTeX. I use PCTeX and I installed the fonts using the  Font List dialog box. I tried to use the package times, and similarly to use

```
  \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
```

Nonetheless, the fonts used are actually the substitute Nimbus.

I guess that the problem is in the 'LT' suffix in the font name, but I have no idea on how to change it. I am not particularly expert in Tex (nor in programming in general), so the more detailed the answers the more appreciated they would be.

Comment: Setting ptm as the default tells LaTeX to use Adobe's Times. However, your installation is probably using the URW clones and so calls NimbusRoman. I guess that ltm might be correct for TimesLT but it depends whether that font is really Times-like or more like one of the other Times fonts. In any case, you need more than the type 1 font for this to work with LaTeX. As the answer below says, you need to generate or obtain the appropriate support files for it to work in TeX.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you'd be satisfied w/ just using

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}
```

There shouldn't be a reason to not accept the clone font which is used.

If you had OpenType version of Times LT, then you could use a TeX variant which directly supports it and install the fonts so that they may be accessed.

If you have access to XeTeX or LuaTeX, this is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times LT Std}
\begin{document}
This is Times by Stanley Morison.
\end{document}
```

If not, you'll need to consult the documentation for PCTeX and see what it says about font installation and follow those instructions.

You should also check the instructions which pre-date OpenType, in particular the `fontinst` manual and Philipp Lehman's *Font Installation Guide* http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/Type1fonts/fontinstallationguide/